# Git/Git Flow: My commited files don't appear on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I am new to Git and soon have to work with a team that uses the Git Flow branching model. While I have understood the theory behind that model pretty well, I am struggling how to get it running for the project.

Here are the commands I am using to set up a small (example) project:

```
git flow init

touch test.txt

git add test.txt

git remote add origin https://github.com/****/some-repository.git

git commit -m "just a test"

git push -u origin master
```

The code above is expected to push the created file "test.txt" to the master branch on the remote, but that does not happen.
All commands are executed without any errors, but taking a look at the GitHub page for that repository it appears to be empty.

One possible cause could be that I am not using a release, hotfix or feature branch but instead work in the develop branch on my machine. On the other hand this does not make sense to me since I just want to set up my project with it's core files, not develop a feature, doing a hotfix or releasing something.

Maybe I am missing some command? Why doesn't my file appear in the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `origin` and `master` parts of `git push -u origin master` indicate that you want to push

- the `master` branch
- to the `origin` remote.

If you're working in `develop` and you want to share that branch you'll want to push the `develop` branch instead.

Try `git push -u origin develop` initially to set your local branch up to track the remote one, and then just `git push origin develop` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! So the problem was that I tried to push my develop branch to the remote's master branch. But what to you mean by initially pushing something using `push -u`? Wouldn't that be an empty push? The remote's develop branch would be the branch to put on a staging server just for release (= merging develop into master), right?

Comment: @Sven, all I mean is that the `-u` argument configures the local branch to track the remote branch. You only need to do it once; afterwards you can omit `-u`.

Comment: @Sven Actually `git push origin master` pushes your own master branch to the remote's master; since you had made no changes on master, that was a no-op.